# Django GenericRelation fields not available during South migration

Tags: python, django, django-south

In a Django project, I have models defined like this :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class TaggedEntry(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class File(TaggedEntry):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    # some more fields

class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    files = generic.GenericRelation(File)
    # some more fields
```

In the project I can use them this way :

```
folder = Folder.objects.get(name="fooo")
for f in folder.files.iterator():
    print f.name
```

I'm now preparing a datamigration with `South` in which I need to access the files of the folders but the code `folder.files.iterator()`

gives me an error :

```
Error in migration: main:0015_contenttype_to_manytomany_step0
AttributeError: 'Folder' object has no attribute 'files'
```

Is it expected?

How can I know the files being part of a folder?

Comment: have you accessed your model over the south provided object: `orm['appname.ModelName']`?

Comment: Yes. I did `for folder in orm.Folder.objects.all():` and then `for f in folder.files.iterator():`. Sorry for not mention it in the question.

Comment: are these models in the same app? if not, could you try to use the `--freeze` option and specify the app where the other model is defined?

Comment: All models are in the same app `main`. I tried `python proj/manage.py datamigration main contenttype_to_manytomany_step0 --freeze main`. This only added a second `'main'` in `complete_apps` which doesn't fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround filtering File's object with the appropriate content_type_id and object_id:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
# ...
folder_contenttype = ContentType.objects.get(name="folder")
for folder in orm.Folder.objects.all():
    for f in orm.File.objects.filter(content_type_id = folder_contenttype.id, object_id = folder.id): # replaces folder.files.iterator():
        # ...
```

This works but is less readable.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I had a bit different case, but your answer showed me the way. I posted answer to more similar problem to my in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47744112/565525.