# Is there a Django South (i)python shell

Tags: python, django, ipython, django-south

I'm preparing several Django models migrations.
As usually when programming, I like to have a shell environment (like ipython) to test/validate in live the operations.

I know that for Django, we have :

```
python django_app/manage.py shell
```

This is really convenient, since all Django objects are available.

For Django's South migrations, model objects are not available as is. See [Django GenericRelation fields not available during South migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759146/django-genericrelation-fields-not-available-during-south-migration) .
Is there a way to load South environment in a (i)python so that operations can be evaluated by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any shell like the one you're asking for. Have I misread your question where you say you like to test your commands on a *live* server using the shell? I strongly advise against that if not.

Is there a reason why you can't test what you're trying to do just using the `manage.py shell`? Or just by backing up your database and creating a migration script, running it, then restoring/rolling back the changes using a backwards migration?

What exactly are you trying to test/figure out?

Comment: I don't do my tests on a live-server. Instead, I copy db content to a test-server and validate my migrations plans. The kind of things I can't test with `manage.py shell` is mentionned in the link I provided.

Comment: Are you doing a schema migration? or a data migration? I'm just wondering why you feel you need to test the migration code.

Comment: I'll have both data and schema migration. I need to test, because I'm not the perfect programmer ... And that the structure of the objects available are not always as imagined (again, see the link in the question).

Comment: Not many people are perfect programmers (We're a rare breed :)). It's reasonable to test things to figure out and South does make it slightly difficult with its ORM replacement. When I need to test/get my head around things like that I typically just run a script (in this case the migration script) and use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to allow me to get a good look around.