# Why GenericRelation fields does not work in Data Migrations(Django)

Tags: python, django, data-migration, django-migrations

I want to make data migration in order to add user read post in database. There is such code:

```
def user_read_posts(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("main", "User")
    Post = apps.get_model("main", "Post")
    Comment = apps.get_model("comments", "Comment")

    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    for comment in comments:
        print (comment.content_object.__class__.__name__)
        if isinstance(comment.content_object, Post):
            comment.user.read_posts.add(comment.content_object)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0039_auto_20160314_0906'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(user_read_posts),
    ]
```

And in line  `print (comment.content_object.__class__.__name__)` django raise error:
`AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'content_object'`

Comment model:

```
class GuidaComment(GenericRelationModel):

    user = models.ForeignKey(GuidaUser)
    text = models.TextField()
```

So what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give the attributes of class `GenericRelationModel` ?

Comment: I use django generic_helpers app.As in docs:  `from generic_helpers.models import GenericRelationModel` Here is a models module https://github.com/marazmiki/django-generic-helpers/blob/master/generic_helpers/models.py

Comment: Consider using this instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/ as I can see that the package hasn't been updated for almost 1 year.

Comment: Thank, but I should use this, as it is not my code for comments. But I forget to add: when I call `content_object` in shell or views, it works perfectly. But no in datamigration

Comment: `>>> print (comment.content_object.__class__.__name__)` `>>> Post`

Answer (score 5):

In `RunPython` migration scripts `apps.get_models()` will get historical version of models, not the latest django models you have in source. These historical models are quite limited. Excerpt from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#historical-models):

> historical models will not have any custom methods that you have
>   defined. They will, however, have the same fields, relationships,
>   managers (limited to those with use_in_migrations = True) and Meta
>   options (also versioned, so they may be different from your current
>   ones).

But that does not mean that you can't use latest and fully functional models by just importing them and using them. In that case you are risking that the migration script won't run correctly in the future - since latest version of model can change (e.g. model method can be renamed, deleted, logic changed etc.). So, it is possible but you need to be aware of the risk using models like this.

[Content types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) is pretty old and rarely changed django contrib application and IMHO it is safe enough to use it like this.

Inspired by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759146/django-genericrelation-fields-not-available-during-south-migration#21777990) and solution I made and use, I have made following draft I hope you will find useful:

```
def user_read_posts(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("main", "User")
    Post = apps.get_model("main", "Post")
    Comment = apps.get_model("comments", "Comment")

    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    for comment in comments:
        try:
            # assuming that Comment has object_id field holding reference to PK
            # of the referenced object 
            ct = ContentType.objects.get(model=comment.content_type.model, 
                                         app_label=comment.content_type.app_label)
            content_object = ct.get_object_for_this_type(pk=comment.object_id)
        except Exception, ex: 
            # TODO: can happen if some content type / model is deleted.
            continue

        print (content_object.__class__.__name__)
        if isinstance(content_object, Post):
            # TODO: maybe you will need to copy/adapt read_posts.add method's logic here
            comment.user.read_posts.add(content_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing `ContentType` as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47744112), I would use `apps.get_model` to get the historic model, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50288027).

Here's what that would look like for the OP's example:

```py
def user_read_posts(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("main", "User")
    Post = apps.get_model("main", "Post")
    Comment = apps.get_model("comments", "Comment")
    
    for comment in Comment.objects.all():
        # get historic model for the specified content_type
        model = apps.get_model(
            app_label=comment.content_type.app_label,
            model_name=comment.content_type.model,
        )
        # get the object with the specified id
        content_object = model.objects.get(id=comment.object_id)

        if isinstance(content_object, Post):
            comment.user.read_posts.add(content_object)


...
```

This assumes `Comment` has `content_type` and `object_id` fields for the generic relation, as in the [generic-relations example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Exception handling has been omitted for clarity.