# 'ContentType' object has no attribute 'model_class' in data migration

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have this in my data migration file:

```
def set_target_user(apps, schema_editor):
    LogEntry = apps.get_model('auditlog', 'LogEntry')
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')
    for entry in LogEntry.objects.filter(target_user=None):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get(id=entry.content_type.id)
        model = ct.model_class()
```

And I got mentioned AttributeError. But it works well in other modules (not migratins). Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `apps.get_model` in a migration, you don't get the actual model class, you get a migration-specific class that is dynamically created with the fields present at that point in the migration history. It won't have any of the methods of the real ContentType model.

You should probably just use `apps.get_model` again to get the historical model for that content type:

```
model = apps.get_model(ct.app_label, ct.model)
```